# jQuery accordion tab link

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion

I'm trying to link to each tab in my jQuery accordion, but can't seem to get it working... I'm not very good with javascript so was wondering if anyone can help.

The code in the header...

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({collapsible: true, header: 'h3', navigation: true});
    $(".accordion:first").show(); // <-- ADD IT HERE, AFTER THIS FIRST HIDE() CALL!
    $("h3 a").click(function(event){
window.location.hash=this.hash;
});
  });
  </script>
```

In the html:

```
    <li><a href="#global">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
```

that should open the following tab:

```
   <h3><a href="#global">Lorem ipsum</a></h3>
```

Any ideas...?

Thanks...

Comment: Please reffer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094766/weird-bug-where-links-dont-work-in-jquery-tabsaccordion/14096413#14096413

Answer (score 1):

for anyone having the same problem, I've managed to fix it starting from scratch on the code and using this: http://jsfiddle.net/tuando/CA8KV/1/

```
$("#accordion").accordion();

$(".section-link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#accordion").accordion("activate", $(this).parent().index());
});
```

​

Excellent and lightweight solution.

Thanks to anyone who looked into it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You used id instead of class.
2. Use attr api of jquery to get the href value

Please Try using

```
  $("#accordion:first").show()
  $("h3 a").click(function(event){
     window.location.hash=$(this).attr('href');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks this still isn't working though... I have this in the header
      <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({collapsible: true, header: 'h3', navigation: true});
$("#accordion:first").show()
  $("h3").click(function(event){
     window.location.hash=$(this).attr('href');
  });
  });
  </script>

And i want to link a navigation on the side to the center tabs...
Any more thoughts...? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`active` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) to define which on to start with ..

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        active:0,
        collapsible: true, 
        header: 'h3', 
        navigation: true
    });
    $("h3 a").click(function(event){
        window.location.hash=this.hash;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that i have a navigation on the side but the links don't open each tab... Not which tab is open to start with... any ideas?