# Weird bug where links don't work in jquery 'tabs+accordion'

Tags: jquery, tabs, hyperlink, accordion

I'm new here - searched everywhere for an answer and can't find one.

I'm using this great tabs+accordion plugin from Codecanyon, but links I am trying to put in the content areas aren't working.

The live site I'm trying to fix is here - http://lrg-international.com/site/ - you'll notice the 'Find out more' buttons in the tabbed area are not clicking through. They can be hovered but clicking them does nothing.

Can anyone tell me why all links after "Link 1" within the 'responsive' tab on this test page aren't clickable/hoverable? Seems to be related to block level elements but I could be totally on the wrong track.

I've asked the developer about this, as it's a paid for plugin, but he hasn't replied. Can anyone help?

Comment: The examples provided work fine for me in Google Chrome version 23.0.1271.97 m.

Comment: Really? The 'Find out more' button within the 'In-house Design' tab actually clicks through to a new page?

Comment: Aaron, can you be specific, which links aren't working for you?

Comment: Allow me to post a video, hold on.

Comment: Okay, I renamed the links on the test page, and links 2 to 5 aren't clickable/hoverable in Chrome, FF or safari.

Comment: If it's the "Find out more" links, then why do they have class="hp-tabs"? That doesn't seem right when they aren't tabs.

Comment: More importantly, please can anyone tell me if the Find Out More button under 'In-house Design' on http://lrg-international.com/site/ is working, and if not, why not? Tearing my hair out!

Comment: Good point - it was just a class name because they were within the homepage tabbed box. I should rename them, it's confusing. Sorry!

Comment: If it's a classname of your own choosing, then it's unlikely to be a problem, but try changing it anyway.

Comment: [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ9YM1YfnlU)

Comment: Renamed them to hpTabbedAreaButton but it didn't work - think it's a more deep rooted problem than that, unfortunately! :(

Comment: @DJDavid98 - thankyou for the video but I may have explained badly - it's the blue 'Find out more' button which isn't clicking through - the tabs themselves work fine!

Comment: Oh, now I see. As far as I can think, the problem is with some part of the code that prevents the click from actually happening.

Comment: By the way, the test page is broken for me.

Comment: Sorry, was changing it in Dropbox to add in some similar buttons. Have now uploaded a zip of all the files. Does that help you or anyone else see what the issue may be? 

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10452828/detached.zip

Thankyou so much for trying!

Comment: I will try something using the zip, not sure if I will be able to, but I guess it's worth a try. Aside from the main thing: the "why choose us" link in the top navbar just links to "#", is that intentional?

Comment: Yeah the site's not finished yet contentwise but needs to go live asap and this bug is killing me :(

Comment: In your downloadable exapmle, the problem seems to be that the elements move "under" the currently displayed content, but still prevent interaction in the area over the image. Click thru to tab 2 and you'll see. Removing the image fixed everything.

Comment: It's got to be either an overlay issue or a bubbling issue. I can't tell which.

Comment: Thankyou so much for looking at it! 

What's bubbling?

(Just checking and trying your answer now! Cheers!)

Comment: Bubbling means the handling (and potentially the interception) of events (eg. a click event) by ancestor elements in addition to the target element. IE bubbles differently from all other browsers.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Thanks for the info. I'm not so hot on jquery so I'm in way over my head with that, but it might be useful to pass on to an expert.

Comment: I just posted a potential solution, based on it being a bubbling issue. Maybe @DJDavid98 can comment. He seems to have good insight into what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

After much appreciated help from David and Beetroot, exploring various avenues, it turned out to be a conflict with a jquery-ui 'tabs' script. The developer told me to remove this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery(function() { 
jQuery(".tabs").tabs(".panes > div"); 
}); 


});
```

from custom.js

Guess plugins need to come up with more unique names for their elements!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it answered!

Comment: Big relief all round Aaron. Hey, let's do again tomorrow ....

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot How about no xD

Answer (score 1):

If it's a bubbling issue, then the following script, at the end of the document's `<head>` *may* cure it.

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(".buttonLRG").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
</script>
```

or, possibly

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("div.tabs").on('click', ".buttonLRG", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
</script>
```

or :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', ".buttonLRG", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
</script>
```

or :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'section[role="tabpanel"]', function(e) {
        alert("at least we're handling the click");
        e.preventDefault();
        var $button = $(".buttonLRG").filter(":visible");
        location.href = $button.attr('href');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's because content is overlapping the link. This won't solve it, since, because the overlap, the click event cannot trigger.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work! Thankyou for trying to help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Aha, so it's an overlay issue, not bubbling?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot As far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

In your downloadable example, the problem seems to be that the elements move "under" the currently displayed content, but still prevent interaction in the area over the embedded things.

On the "official" demo page, the problem can be noticed as well, but they cleverly formatted the first tab so it isn't getting overlepped from the image under it.

**EDIT:** Testing the live website I found that changing the `.js .tabs > section` selector's  `visibility: hidden;` to `display: none;` AND changing `.tabs > section[aria-expanded="true"]`selector's `visibility: visible;` to `display: block;` solved the problem. You could try that. It does seem like that the 'bubbling' issue may come into play, so try both this and the other answer together.

Comment: Ah that didn't work on the live site sadly. And it is stopping the container in 'nested instance' tab wrapping the the correct height of the images. DAMMIT! How has no one noticed this wrong with the plugin?!

PS thankyou again!

Comment: Glad to help. You really should notify the developer.

Comment: As I said, I have, but I guess he hasn't got back to me because it's holiday season. Sadly I have a deadline. I'd happily pay ££ for someone to fix this but have no idea who could help!!

Comment: @Aaron Can you create a zip from the live site contents?

Comment: It's a Wordpress site so that's near impossible! 

I tried and it's here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10452828/LRG-International.zip

It's all messed up at larger widths because of the responsive stuff (I think) BUT if you resize the window down to 900px, making it change into the accordion, you can recreate the problem and see the links not clicking through.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10452828/LRG-International.zip

Comment: I wonder if absolutely positioning the offending buttons, to match their natural flow positions, and giving them a high z-index would cure this?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Tested, no.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot & Aaron: If it's possible, we could move this to a 3 people chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21917/discussion-between-djdavid98-and-beetroot-beetroot)

Comment: I can't talk in chat because I'm new and don't have enough reputation yet! (Woe is me)

I tried that edit fix you suggested and it didn't work. I was so hopeful, too. I so appreciate your efforts, thankyou guys!

Did that fix work on that manky zip of the live site then?

Comment: Hi Aaron - what a rotten trick! David and I tossed around a couple of ideas - but no joy yet.

Comment: @Aaron You just can't write, or you can't see anything from what we're typing?