# JQuery Accordion content links don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to JQuery and I am implementing accordion.  I'm having issues with having more than one hyperlink in the content.  Essentially I have one dropdown and a list of links.  For some reason only the first hyperlink works.  They are all hyperlinks and come up as so but only the first one is clickable.  Anyone have some insight?  This person had the same issue but the code he commented out doesn't exist in my js.  [Weird bug where links don't work in jquery 'tabs+accordion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094766/weird-bug-where-links-dont-work-in-jquery-tabsaccordion)

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion(
    {
        collapsible: true, active:false, header:"h3"}
    );      
    $( ".selector" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "fill" });
});

</script>

<div id ="accordion">   
        <h3> &nbsp </h3>
         <ul class="ui-accordion-container">
            <li><a class="accordion-label" href="#">this is a test blah blah blah</a></li>
            <li><a class="accordion-label" href="#">this is a test blah blah blah</a></li>
            <li><a class="accordion-label" href="#">this is a test blah blah blah</a></li>
        </ul>       
</div>
```

Comment: A JsFiddle I created works in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/GnHBT/. What browser, version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: Worked in Firefox too http://jsfiddle.net/RTUmD/

Comment: Is that everything you have in your page? It could be some other element covering your links. Use the developers tool and make sure there is not another element covering your links.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  One for showing me that my code was actually working.  AndrewK that site is awesome.  Hanlet you were right.  I couldn't post everything because it's a full site with elements everywhere.  There was a div that was on top of it.  I set the z-index to verify.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that containing div had styling of `::before` which was displayed on top of my links and that's why there weren't clickable. Removing that styling did the job.